# Mysql - to create a new table or not to create

Tags: php, mysql, orm, model

I've the following model `Order`.

Any order can have such status as  `new`, `in work`, `being delivered`, `on storage`, `executed`, `cancelled`.

I found the following code in the model:

[image]

As for now every order has  number what identifies its status.

If I started the project from scratch I would rather create a separate table with the name let's say `order_status` and insert primary keys from it into `Order` table.

What approach is more preferred and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take a column named as status and set the number what ever it is like 1,2,3,4,5,this approach is more convenient than creating a new relation ship table because it uses extra join to retrieve status,it will be useful if order have multiple status at the same time otherwise you can update status of that order in same table.